# Sed how to get first result from pattern

Tags: sed

I'm trying to extract the first index number in a found pattern, sed keeps returning me number 2.

The pattern I use:

```
AUDIO_LANG=Angielski
cat /home/ddd/getaudiomenulist | sed 's/.*'$AUDIO_LANG' DTS-HD[^:]*:\([^,]*\).*/\1/' | grep -o '[0-9]*$'
```

So pattern gives me index":2 but I want **1**.

File data getaudiomenulist:

```
{"success":true,"msg":"","file_path":"","audio_list":[{"name":"1/9 Angielski DTS-HD MA 5.1","index":1,"selected":true},{"name":"2/9 Angielski DTS-HD MA Stereo","index":2,"selected":false},{"name":"3/9 Francuski Dolby Digital","index":3,"selected":false},{"name":"4/9 Niemiecki Dolby Digital","index":4,"selected":false},{"name":"5/9 Włoski Dolby Digital","index":5,"selected":false},{"name":"6/9 Hiszpański Dolby Digital","index":6,"selected":false},{"name":"7/9 Hiszpański Dolby Digital","index":7,"selected":false},{"name":"8/9 Portugalski Dolby Digital","index":8,"selected":false},{"name":"9/9 Angielski Dolby Digital","index":9,"selected":false}]}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: `grep -m 1 -Po "$AUDIO_LANG"' DTS-HD[^:]*:\K[^,]+' /home/ddd/getaudiomenulist | head -1`

Comment: I like this solution, thx.

Comment: @jasko887 don't use grep to parse json

Comment: @Paolo
even if I have code inside file? what is the problem with grep?

Comment: @jasko887 grep is not a json parser. as soon as your task becomes more complex you'll struggle. learn to use the right tool for the job, which in this case is `jq`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew are we able to "overcome" this?
grep: The -P option is not supported, system is very old and closed.

Comment: You should check the answers below. If they help - upvote and if they do not - write a comment to the person who answered and ask for more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `jq` to work with json:

```bash
$ AUDIO_LANG=Angielski
$ jq --arg v "$AUDIO_LANG" 'first(.audio_list[] | select(.name | contains($v)).index)' /home/ddd/getaudiomenulist
1
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you should use a json-aware tool like `jq` for this.

---

The reason you don't get the first index as your result is that your `sed` command starts with `.*`. This will consume as much of the string as possible while still allowing a match (including  all the other language matches).

Assuming the input data is always on a single line, this alternative might work:

```
AUDIO_LANG=Angielski
sed '
    # skip line unless language exists
    /'"$AUDIO_LANG"' DTS-HD/!d

    # delete up to first instance of language
    s//\n/
    s/.*\n//

    # find and delete up to subsequent index
    s/"index":/\n/
    s/.*\n//

    # delete everything after the number
    s/,.*//
' /home/ddd/getaudiomenulist
```

---

**Note:** Using `\n` in the replacement is not portable.

For portability, an escaped literal newline should be used:

```
AUDIO_LANG=Angielski
sed '
    # skip line unless language exists
    /'"$AUDIO_LANG"' DTS-HD/!d

    # delete up to first instance of language
    s//\
/
    s/.*\n//

    # find and delete up to subsequent index
    s/"index":/\
/
    s/.*\n//

    # delete everything after the number
    s/,.*//
' /home/ddd/getaudiomenulist
```

Comment: alternative using awk: `awk -v RS=} -F "$AUDIO_LANG"'.*"index":' 'NF==2 && !seen++ { print 0+$2 }' /home/ddd/getaudiomenulist`

Answer (score -1):

Try this I guess :-

```
AUDIO_LANG=Angielski
cat /home/ddd/getaudiomenulist | 
  sed -n '/"'$AUDIO_LANG' DTS-HD/{s/.*index":\([0-9]*\),.*/\1/p;q;}'
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: @KnockbackIV Thx I tried but no result.